# Struts html:text styleclass

Tags: css, jsp, struts-1

I am working on Struts program and come across the `html` tag with a `styleClass` attribute in one of the JSP pages.

So, it looks something like:

```
<html:text name = "XXX" property="YYY" styleClass="ZZZ" ...
```

I have tried to look for `ZZZ.css` but none exist. Can anyone please tell me how `styleClass` works? Is `ZZZ` defined in some particular file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `css` files in your page, and `styleClass` `ZZZ..` should be one of the `css` selectors.

See [html:text](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/text.html) tag documentation

From documentation:

`CSS stylesheet class to be applied to this HTML element (renders a "class" attribute).`

Comment: Finally found it defined in one of the css... But it's something like .contentModule>form input.ZZZ

Answer (score 1):

It is not a file, it is the html class attribute.

The equivalent code is:

```
<input type="text" class="ZZZ" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**The `styleClass` works the same like `class` attribute in HTML.**

CSS rules could be in the same document using   `<style type="text/css">` or in the linked document like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<html:rewrite page='/css/ZZZ.css'/>">
```